# Multiplying raster by scalar in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am using 
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/arithmetic-function.htm 
and https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/calculator-function.htm

I am getting error messages with zero feedback. Just "Failed to apply calculator"

The raster is projecting fine on my map, and I can multiply / subtract it with itself just fine in the arithmetic, but calculator never works.

We have tried:

1. single raster input, calculations like "value * 2"
2. same raster in both inputs

We're using a tif, does that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output fails when you use the wrong variables, operators or inputs. A TIFF image is fully supported, maybe you aren't calling variables in the right way.

`value * 2` is only valid if `value` is set as a raster variable, for example (using a L8 image, TIFF file):

[image]

The result is in accordance with what is established as expression:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the clarification, this is exactly our setup. in the end our problem was we didnt have the right license. the Spatial Analyst was missing. shame the error messages didnt pick that up